# Fixed bar in a scrollable kivy window

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

Hello fellow StackOverFlow users,

how would one go about creating a bar with a fixed position in kivy?

I am using a GridLayout and ScrollView in order to have a scrollable kivy application, and I want to have a horizontal bar with a few Buttons on top, that will remain there regardless of where you scrolled.

Does anyone here know how can I do that?

Thanks,
S. Badui

Comment: Please make an attempt to code this and post what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a BoxLayout. Place a Label or another wigdet as well as your scrollable Gridview in it. Then you can still scroll and the 'other' widget will always be visible.